# Developing in a Docker image that's under version control

Tags: r, github, docker, jekyll

Currently have a pipeline that I use to build reports in `R` and publish in `Jekyll`. I keep my files under version control in github and that's been working great so far.

Recently I began thinking about how I might take `R`, `Ruby` and `Jekyll` and build a docker image that any of my coworkers could download and run the same report without having all of the packages and gems set up on their computer. I looked at Docker Hub and found that the automated builds for git commits were a very interesting feature.

I want to build an image that I could use to run this configuration and keep it under version control as well and keep it up to date in Docker Hub. How does something like this work?

If I just kept my current setup I could add a dockerfile to my repo and Docker Hub would build my image for me, I just think it would be interesting to run my work on the same image.

Any thoughts on how a pipeline like this may work?

Comment: You wouldn't create one image to contain all of your components but one image per repo (R app, Jekyll site, Ruby app). You just add a Dockerfile in each github repo. You put them all together using a docker-compose.yml file at the client side. Docker for mac or windows are great for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Hub build service should work (https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/). You can also consider using gitlab-ci or travis ci (gitlab will be useful for privet projects, it also provides privet docker registry).

You should have two Dockerfiles one with all dependencies and second very minimalistic one for reports (builds will be much faster). Something like:

```
FROM base_image:0.1
COPY . /reports
WORKDIR /reports
RUN replace-with-requiered-jekyll-magic
```

Dockerfile above should be in your reports repository.

In 2nd repository you can crate base image with all the tools and nginx or something for serving static files. Make sure that nginx www-root is set to /reports. If you need to update the tools just update base_mage tag in Dockerfile for reports.